# there is strange malloc functions which I not used

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, intel-pin

I use pin to analyze my simple program.

It has 4 malloc functions, however, when I use pin with pintool named malloctrace, it shows more than 4 mallocs.

What are these malloc functions?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. below items are code what I make and result of pintool.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
    int *test1 = (int*)malloc(SIZE* sizeof(int));
    int *test2 = (int*)malloc(SIZE* sizeof(int));
    int i, j;
    int *test3 = (int*)malloc(16*sizeof(int));
    int *test4 = (char*)malloc(SIZE* sizeof(int));

    test1[0] = 2;
    test1[2] = 3;
    test2[0] = 5;

    printf("test1's addr : %p , test1's val = %d    \n", test1, test1[0]);
    printf("test1's addr : %p , test1's val = %d    \n", &test1[1], test1[1]);
    printf("test2's addr : %p , test2's val = %d    \n", &test1[9], test1[9]);


    return 0;
}
```

---

```
       name           size          start_addr           malloc_IP          access_cnt
     malloc          0x589                   0      0x7ffff7de557e                   0
     malloc          0x489                   0      0x7ffff7de557e                   0
     malloc            0xf                   0      0x7ffff7ddd29e                   0
     malloc           0x4b                   0      0x7ffff7df01b2                   0
     malloc           0x28                   0      0x7ffff7de1fe7                   0
     malloc         0x14a0                   0      0x7ffff7de202c                   0
     malloc           0x28                   0      0x7ffff7de22ad                   0
     malloc           0x48                   0      0x7ffff7ddf9d3                   0
     malloc           0x5c                   0      0x7ffff7ddf9d3                   0
     malloc           0x5c                   0      0x7ffff7ddf9d3                   0
     malloc           0x39                   0      0x7ffff7ddf9d3                   0
     malloc           0x20                   0      0x7ffff7de294e                   0
     malloc          0x492                   0      0x7ffff7de557e                   0
     malloc           0x20                   0      0x7ffff7de57ed                   0
     malloc           0x28                   0      0x7ffff7de776f                   0
     malloc           0x38                   0      0x7ffff7de7900                   0
     malloc           0x48                   0      0x7ffff7deab5a                   0
     malloc           0x48                   0      0x7ffff7deab5a                   0
     malloc          0x228                   0      0x7ffff7deab5a                   0
     malloc           0x90                   0      0x7ffff7deab5a                   0
     malloc          0x410                   0      0x7ffff7ddaf22                   0
     malloc          0x110                   0      0x7ffff7debd52                   0
     malloc          0x190                   0            0x4013d2                   0
     malloc          0x190            0x603010            0x4013d2                   0
     malloc          0x190            0x6031b0            0x4013e0                   0
     malloc           0x40            0x603350            0x4013ee                   0
     malloc          0x190            0x6033a0            0x4013fc                   0
       free              0                   0            0x401688                   0
       free              0                   0            0x401688                   0
       free              0                   0            0x401688                   0
       free              0                   0            0x401688                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016b0                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016b0                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016d7                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016d7                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016d7                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016d7                   0
       free              1                   0            0x4016e8                   0
       free              0                   0            0x4016e8                   0
       free              0                   0            0x401718                   0
       free              0                   0            0x401718                   0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that other stuff may be calling `malloc` under the covers, including the C runtime code (as an example, for thread-specific data used by things such as `strtok`) or even your analysis tool itself.

If you examine the start address of all those memory blocks, you'll notice that all but the ones you do are `0` (100 4-byte `int` variables take op `400` or `0x190` bytes, 16 of them take up `64` or `0x40` bytes).

That *may* be relevant here, although it may also be that you're the only one not cleaning up after yourself :-)

---

By the way, you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in C since it can hide certain subtle errors, such as when your `int` and pointer sizes are different widths and you forget to include `stdlib.h`, both of which may be possible here given you're running in a 64-bit environment.

C is perfectly capable of implicitly casting the `void *` returned from `malloc` into any other pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb to find out what is going on and who calls `malloc()`. In your case you will a see a lot breaks in ld-linux.so:

```
Breakpoint 3, malloc (n=n@entry=136) at dl-minimal.c:93
93  in dl-minimal.c
(gdb) where
#0  malloc (n=n@entry=136) at dl-minimal.c:93
#1  0xb7ff3baa in calloc (nmemb=nmemb@entry=17, size=size@entry=8) at dl-minimal.c:113
#2  0xb7fef628 in allocate_dtv (result=result@entry=0xb7e00900) at dl-tls.c:296
#3  0xb7fefaf8 in _dl_allocate_tls_storage () at dl-tls.c:364
#4  0xb7fdecc7 in init_tls () at rtld.c:771
#5  0xb7fe0fcd in dl_main (phdr=0x8048034, phnum=9, user_entry=0xbfffedbc, auxv=0xbfffef5c) at rtld.c:1819
#6  0xb7ff33b6 in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=start_argptr@entry=0xbfffee50, dl_main=dl_main@entry=0xb7fdf720 <dl_main>) at ../elf/dl-sysdep.c:241
#7  0xb7fe2dd4 in _dl_start_final (arg=0xbfffee50) at rtld.c:337
#8  _dl_start (arg=0xbfffee50) at rtld.c:563
#9  0xb7fdf197 in _start () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

[_start](http://learningpearls.blogspot.ru/2011/02/start-function-inside-c.html) function is enter point to a program and it is called before main() function. So it is not visible in the program text but it exists and it has a calls to different functions at start up time.
Also there is `ldd` utility which shows all the dynamic libraries used by executable:

```
ldd main
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7724000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7547000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7725000)
```

So any of linked to executable file libraries can use malloc().

Answer (score 1):

The malloc calls which are important for you is this

```
 malloc          0x190            0x603010            0x4013d2                   0
 malloc          0x190            0x6031b0            0x4013e0                   0
 malloc           0x40            0x603350            0x4013ee                   0
 malloc          0x190            0x6033a0            0x4013fc
```

Rest are being called internally by some system calls .